# Flutter convert ui.Image to a file

Tags: flutter, dart

The code:

```dart
final tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
            File file = File("${tempDir.path}/image.png");

            ui.Image croppedImage = await cropController.croppedBitmap();

            final data = await croppedImage.toByteData(
              format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png,
            );

            final bytes = data.buffer.asUint64List();

            file = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
```

The cropController is from the `crop_image` plugin.

I get this error when I posted `Image.file`

```dart
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `Uint8List`, not a `Uint64List`. `writeAsBytes` is truncating your 64-bit ints to 8-bit ints and you're losing 3/4 of the data.

Change

```dart
final bytes = data.buffer.asUint64List();
```

to

```dart
final bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
```